# SPO - Simulate search being down

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-api

I'm creating an notification message to let users know if SharePoint Online search is down. What's the best way to simulate this?

Right now, I'm thinking to call an AJAX request to `https://mySPOsite/_api/search/query?Querytext='SearchOnlineCheck'` and if I get a 200 or 204 back, then I know SPO search is online. Is this good enough?

And to actually test this, how would I make it so that search is "down"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i am surprised to know that SharePoint online search will be down at any given amount of time that you can notice..

But still i would advise you test it with SharePoint 2013 on-prem addition by stopping the search service application or search services in the front end servers so you will be able test the same behavior.

Comment: It has happened twice to a client. It was isolated to their tenant so it wasn't like every SPO farm didn't have search. But yes, it does happen haha (0.01%??)